# which measurement is the height and weight in netbeans properties

Tags: java, netbeans, components

can anyone please tell me in which measurement is the height and weight in net-beans IDE component properties meant to be.
whether the measurement in cm, mm, or inches .... what does the 501 and 20 stands for ?

[image]

Comment: It's most likely pixels, failing that dialog units

Answer (score 0):

Those measurements are in pixels.  Measurements in mm or inches have no meaning when I project the monitor on a distant wall.

As an aside, they are only ***suggestions*** that the layout manager will often ignore.

Answer (score 0):

The Layout Manager will ignore the Width and Height values except when you are using the Null Layout.